# Redirecting to AngularJS snapshots in Spring Boot

Tags: angularjs, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, seo

Under path `src/main/resources/static` of my Spring Boot app I have the sources of my AngularJS 1.5 app. Using Grunt I can build it minified to `src/main/resources/static/dist` for production. But for development mode I use the sources because I don't want to wait for build process on changes.

When I detect that the app runs in production/staging, I use the `dist` folder dynamically using this config:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (isProduction() || isStaging()) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/dist/");
        } else {
            super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        }
    }

    private boolean isProduction() {
        return Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("production");
    }

    private boolean isStaging() {
        return Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("staging");
    }
}
```

This works perfectly.
To start caring about SEO for the Angular app, I added `grunt-html-snapshots` to my build process so that snapshots are built to `src/main/resources/static/dist/snapshots/`. See the resulting structure:

[image: snapshots directory structure]

How could I now redirect to the snapshots if I detect `escaped_fragment` in a request path? Should I implement something based on the embedded Tomcat? Or some rewrite in the Spring Boot code? In production between Apache2 and the embedded Tomcat?

`html-snapshots` suggests to solve it like this for a plain Apache2:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/snapshots [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /snapshots/$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

Does someone have experiences how to do it best?

Comment: take a look into JHipster project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to look into the project. But can you describe it a bit more concrete? I built myself a project now and played around with it. But I didn't find anything regarding my question.